# Question about being a resident

Tags: united-states, non-resident, oregon

I moved to Oregon in July 2014 from Nevada.  I have OR DMV and Voter's registration.  Am I considered a resident of Oregon now?

Comment: Need more information.  "resident" is a term that can be defined differently depending on context.

Comment: State residency usually varies, and depends on your reason for asking. For in-state tuition rates, most universities and colleges require that the student be domiciled in the state with a parent or as a financially independent person no less than 12 consecutive months prior to admission. Also, this doesn't appear to be related to money or personal finance

Comment: Please specify the purpose of the question.  For example, in order to qualify for "resident" in-state tuition at a state university, many schools demand quite a bit of documentation from students who move into the state specifically to attend that school.  On the other hand, the state where the school is located is perfectly happy to start collecting tax from you the minute you begin earning income there!

Answer (score 3):

One thing to consider besides what rules [Oregon](http://www.oregon.gov/dor/PERTAX/Pages/faq-qa_forms.aspx) has, is what rules your old state have. Of course the lack of income tax in Nevada means that most people are trying to convince their new state they are still a resident of Nevada.

> You are a full-year Oregon resident if you live in Oregon all year.
>   You are also a full-year Oregon resident, even if you live outside
>   Oregon, if all of the following are true:
>
> - You think of Oregon as your permanent home.
> - Oregon is the center of your financial, social, and family life.
> - Oregon is the place you intend to come back to when you are away.
>
> **Part-year resident**: You are a part-year resident if you moved into or out of Oregon during the tax year.

The requirement for financial life means that you should: change all your Nevada banks to Oregon banks; Change all your mail to Oregon; Sell any property or end any leases you have in Nevada.

Or course you need to research the rules for [in state college tuition](http://admissions.uoregon.edu/freshmen/residency/FAQ), [death with dignity](http://www.cnn.com/2014/10/07/opinion/maynard-assisted-suicide-cancer-dignity/)  if any apply to you. In border areas you must be careful to establish residency for children to attend public schools. Some families try to cheat to get their children into a better school.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are asking for Tax purposes.

In Oregon, there is a distinction between Full-Year and Partial-Year residency for Tax purposes. You are most likely considered a Partial-Year resident since you moved into the state last year. However, there are also special conditions under which you might be considered a Full-Year resident, so check out the state's tax residency rules [here](http://www.oregon.gov/dor/PERTAX/Pages/faq-qa_forms.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of involves personal finance, and sort of not. But it's an interesting question, so let's call it on topic?

Short answer: [yes](http://pattyinglishms.hubpages.com/hub/state-residency).

Long answer: it depends who's asking. If you're trying to qualify for [in-state tuition](http://catalog.oregonstate.edu/ChapterDetail.aspx?key=258), for example, you need to have been in state for a certain amount of time. For tax purposes, the first year you move to a new state you need to file [part-time resident returns](http://www.oregon.gov/dor/PERTAX/Pages/faq-qa_forms.aspx) in your previous and current state of residency